# Using Vaadin Components with snowpack

Tags: vaadin, snowpack

I'm trying to use Vaadin Components with [snowpack](http://snowpack.dev). Specifically just to recreate the [basic app layout example](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-app-layout/2.0.2/demo/#element-basic-demos). But I get the following error message. What does this mean? How do I fix it?

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> SyntaxError: indirect export not found: IronResizableBehavior
> http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/@polymer.iron-resizable-behavior.iron-resizable-behavior.v3.0.1.js [:4:9]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report, we now have a pull request for fixing the issue: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/pull/2405

The fix is currently expected to become available in Vaadin 20.0.8

Comment: great, thanks!   
while I have you, is it possible to use vaadin without a build tool? like via skypack?

Comment: I'm not personally familiar, but I hear there might be some issue with Skypack CDN. A colleague linked me this, though, in case you'd find it useful: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/2004#issuecomment-878477706